# LWJGL won't create window with GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL to build a game.

But there is a problem. When I call glfwCreateWindow, LWJGL throws an error and does not creates window.

Here is output:

```
[2016-05-14 22:42:04.665] [CubeSystem/INFO] Starting graphics engine...
[LWJGL] GLFW_API_UNAVAILABLE error
    Description : WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
    Stacktrace  :
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1168)
        org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1251)
        Tmk.MyAdventure.System.CubeSystem.Init(CubeSystem.java:37)
        Tmk.MyAdventure.Main.main(Main.java:13)
[2016-05-14 22:42:04.740] [CubeSystem/ERROR] Cannot create window.
```

I don't know why it says that the driver does not appear to support OpenGL.

My computer runs OpenGL games fine. Also, I updated driver to latest version and still shows this message.

I got same message when I run on outside of IDE.

Here is code:

```
....

public class CubeSystem {
    private static Logger l = new Logger("CubeSystem");

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 480;

    private long window;

    public CubeSystem() {
    }

    public boolean Init() {
        l.Info("Starting graphics engine...");
        //Configure error stream
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
        if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            l.Err("Cannot initialize GLFW.");
            return false;
        }
        //Configure window
        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, "My Adventure", NULL, NULL);
        if(window == NULL) {
            l.Err("Cannot create window.");
            return false;
        }

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).release();

        return true;
    }
}
```

NOTE: Begins at Init() method.

Comment: Have you linked the LWJGL natives correctly?

Comment: `WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL`. Either a bug in LWJGL, in which case you could try a different version, or your computer doesn't like GLFW

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing additional hints.Here is how I use GLFW.(C++)

```
 if (!glfwInit()) {

        throw;

    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);//using OpenGL 4.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);



#ifdef _DEBUG

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);

#else
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_FALSE);

#endif

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 8);
    _glfwWin = glfwCreateWindow(winW, winH, "Display", NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: I tried adding additional hints. But didn't worked. Also, I tried different OpenGL version like 1.1, 1.5 and 2.1, all of them didn't worked.